# How do I document the Jupyter Notebook Profile startup?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

When I start up the Jupyter Notebook I've modified the `ipython_config.py` in my ipython profile to automatically load `numpy` as `np`:

```
c.InteractiveShellApp.exec_lines = [
    'import numpy as np',
    ]
```

This works great. When I start up a Notebook, in the first cell I can immediately call all of the numpy library via `np.`. However, if I'm sharing this Notebook via a gist or some other method, these imports are not explicitly shown. This is suboptimal as it makes clear reproducibility impossible.

**My question:** Is there a way that I could automatically populate the first cell of a new Notebook with the code that I'm importing? (Or some other similar way to document the imports that are occurring for the Notebook).

I'd be OK with removing the `exec_lines` option and pre-populating the code that I have to run myself or some other solution that gets at the main idea: clear reproducibility of the code that I'm initially importing in the Notebook.

**Edit**

A deleted answer that might be helpful to people landing here: I found [jupyter_boilerplate](https://github.com/moble/jupyter_boilerplate) which  as an installable Notebook extension "Adds a customizable menu item to Jupyter (IPython) notebooks to insert boilerplate snippets of code" -- would allow one to easily create a starting code snippet that could be filled in.

**Sidenote to [MLavoie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3396821/mlavoie) because "comments disabled on deleted / locked posts / reviews"**

Yes, you are right that:

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review – [MLavoie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3396821/mlavoie) Jul 8 '16 at 17:27

But, you'll notice, that this is a *widget* to be *installed*, so there isn't relevant code to paste here. It was unhelpful to delete the above answer.

Comment: @JBWhitemore Don't like my answer?

Comment: 1) I accepted it, 2) you misspelled my name, 3) update your profile ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Almost* automatically:

`%load startup.py`

Put import/config code in a version controlled file on your PYTHONPATH and %load it into the first cell.

This has the advantage of allowing you to use different startup code without tweaking your startup config, and notebooks remain portable, i.e. send the notebook and startup file to other users and they can run it without tweaking their startup config.

Answer (score -1):

Create a notebook that contains the preparations you want and use that as a template. That is, copy it to a new file and open it.